# Diferentiating $\int_x^{2x} e^{t^2}dt$.

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to differentiate the following integral

$$\int_x^{2x} e^{t^2}dt$$

I've tried, with $a \in [x, 2x]$

$$\int_x^{2x} e^{t^2}dt = \int_x^{a} e^{t^2}dt + \int_a^{2x} e^{t^2}dt$$

and, through the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, it'd be (if I'm not mistaken)

$$e^{(2x)^2}-e^{x^2}$$

But, the result should be

$$2e^{(2x)^2}-e^{x^2}$$

Why's that? Where does that $2$ come from? Did I make some mistake along the way?

Comment: apply leibniz rule of integration

Comment: It come from the chain rule.

Comment: Got it. It was simple.

Comment: @Rodrigo Funny, I just dealt with a similar problem yesterday. Glad you got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g(x)=f(2x)$, then $g'(x)=2f'(2x)$ (chain rule). Apply this when you differentiate $\int_a^{2x}e^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt$.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Se o vir pela faculdade, agradeço-lhe em pessoa.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
& \frac d {dx} \left( \int_x^{2x} e^{t^2} \, dt \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac d {dx} \left( \int_0^{2x} e^{t^2} \, dt + \int_x^0 e^{t^2} \, dt \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac d {dx} \left( \int_0^u e^{t^2} \, dt - \int_0^x e^{t^2}\, dt \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \underbrace{\left( \frac d {du} \int_0^u e^{t^2}\,dt \cdot \frac {du}{dx} \right)}_\text{chain rule} - e^{x^2} \\[12pt]
= {} & e^{u^2} \cdot 2 - e^{x^2} \\[8pt]
= {} & e^{(2x)^2} \cdot 2 - e^{x^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: Okay means we can use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Part 1 only when the lower limit is a constant, am I right?

Comment: @adeshmishra : Or at least you can use it in that very simple form only then.

Comment: Do you mean that FTC 1 can be used in other forms also? Will you please tell me what that form is? Or should I ask it as a new question?

Comment: @adeshmishra : I actually had in mind trivial variations, such as $$ \frac d{dx} \int_x^0 g(u)\,du = -g(u), \quad \text{etc.} $$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle {\int_{a}^{2x}}e^{t^2}dt  +\int_{x}^{a}e^{t^2}dt;$

1)$u=(t/2);$

$F(x):=2\displaystyle{\int_{a/2}^{x}}e^{4u^2}du$;

2) $G(x)=-\displaystyle{\int_{a}^{x}}e^{t^2}dt$.

FTC:

$F'(x)=2e^{4x^2}$, and $G'(x)=-e^{x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

You get $2e^{4x^2}-e^{x^2}$, by splitting up the integral and then applying the fundamental theorem of calculus (and the chain rule).